# How to remove device access allows from installing Exchange Account

Tags: exchange

I allowed access to manage my Android device (Galaxy S7) when adding my Exchange account.

I've removed that mail account but I would like to make sure that the Exchange account or organization has zero ability to manage my personal device any longer.  Is there anyway to ensure this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open settings go to Security, then Device administrators. Now you have a list of all apps that can manage your device. If your email app is listed you can click on it and select "deactivate this device administrator" to disable it.

If your email app is not in this list, your organization has no longer any access to your device.

Comment: Thanks for heads up although small note the steps to get there were incorrect on latest Android though i found it.

Comment: Glad you found it. Every manufacturer does it slightly different (I only have stock android or htc sense to compare, no samsung device). Also if it's the right answer please accept it as correct answer. thx

Answer (score 1):

if you have removed or deleted the account, it's already ensured that no one else can access your device or manage account.

Comment: Any reference material?  Any way to see of device has been accessed since deleting?

Comment: You should be able to remove your ActiveSync devices by logging into Outlook Web App via web browser (I am not sure what version of Exchange you have, we use Office 365).  You can remove by going to Settings icon - Mail - under General select Mobile Devices - highlight the device you wish to remove and click on the "-" icon to remove it.